# Роутинг в kohana 3.2 не работает на локалхосте

Tags: kohana

Если это возможно, то помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с роутингом в kohana 3.2. На сайте работают 2 странички:

1. [h32149.srv5.test-hf.ru/kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/](http://h32149.srv5.test-hf.ru/kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/)
2. [h32149.srv5.test-hf.ru/kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/products](http://h32149.srv5.test-hf.ru/kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/products)

Правила роутинга простейшие.

Но ссылка на страничку `kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/products` не работает на localhost-e. Браузер показывает сообщение об ошибке:

> Not Found  The requested URL
> /kohana/kohana-3.2-master-1/products
> was not found on this server. 
> Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at
> localhost Port 80

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как бы решить её, скажите, пожалуйста.

[Ссылка](http://h32149.srv5.test-hf.ru/kozip/kohana.zip) на архив. Понимаю, что неудобно.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в kohana-3.2-master-1/system/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls.md. Должно помочь.